# How do I fix this missing font?

Tags: macos, fonts, safari

At some point (years ago?) my safari starting not having some fonts. Example is this page: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/others/

How can I fix this?

[image: screenshot demonstrating missing fonts]

Comment: Do you have access to Garamond (the font missing here) e.g. in TextEdit? In Font Book, is there Garamond? Is there an error symbol? What happens when you select it and run *File » Verify Font*? What happens when you (as a last resort) execute *File » Restore Standard Fonts*?

Comment: Garamond is gone! I don't have ***File » Restore Standard Fonts*** -- I'm on 10.6

Comment: Install Microsoft Office 2008 Trial and uninstall it again. Garamond is part of that. Not sure why Safari doesn't fallback on other fonts though. Does it help to [clear font caches (6.)](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/327/327791.html)?

Comment: okay so your suggestions led me down the right path... in my library/fonts directory there were some fonts with messed up names including a garamond... i deleted all those fonts and now garamond works again! however it's odd because i can't find it when i search... maybe it's because it got cached somewhere when i was playing with the downloads from garamond.org... if it disappears after i reboot or something i'll just reinstall them from there.

Comment: You're welcome. Consider posting the answer yourself to let others with the same problem know how you fixed it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: I looked in ~/Library/Fonts and there were a bunch of fonts with odd names (from a bad rsync years ago where characters somehow became html escaped).

I deleted the entire contents of that directory and everything cleared up, although I still can't find Garamond anywhere on the system. But it definitely is available.